# Как получить доступ к UISpite?

Tags: c#, unity3d, спрайт

Есть код, который создаёт объекты с компонентом `Image`, в котором я хочу заменить `Source Image` на один из дефолтных, через код.

**Пример:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class PotionManager : MonoBehaviour {

    Image sourceImage;
    private float timer=25;
    static int COUNT_OF_ORDERS = 0;
    public Transform parent;
    public List<PotionAsset> potionList = new List<PotionAsset>();
    private float posX,posY,posZ;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer >= 30)
        {
            CreateOrderHolder();
        }
    }

    void CreateOrderHolder()
    {
        posX = 160 * COUNT_OF_ORDERS + 80;
        posY = -70;
        posZ = 0;

        COUNT_OF_ORDERS++;

        GameObject temp = new GameObject("Potion Order " + COUNT_OF_ORDERS, typeof(RectTransform));
        temp.transform.SetParent(parent);
        temp.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(posX, posY, posZ);
        temp.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f);
        temp.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchorMax = new Vector2(0, 1);
        temp.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 1);

        CreatePotionHolder(temp.transform);

        timer = 0;
    }

    void CreatePotionHolder(Transform parent)
    {
        posX = 0;
        posY = 13.5f;
        posZ = 0;

        GameObject temp = new GameObject("PotionHolder", typeof(RectTransform), typeof(Image));

        temp.transform.SetParent(parent);
        temp.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(posX, posY, posZ);
        temp.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        temp.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(100,50);

        sourceImage = temp.GetComponent<Image>();
        sourceImage.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Resources/unity_builtin_extra/UISprite");
        Debug.Log(sourceImage.sprite);
    }

}
```

Итого `sourceImage.sprite` возвращает `null`. Пробовал добавлять в конце формат файла png,psd. Не помогло.

Comment: уберите из "Resources/unity_builtin_extra/UISprite" ресурс что бы было так 

        sourceImage.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("unity_builtin_extra/UISprite");

Comment: @Andrey Я уже это пробовал и это не помогло.

Comment: Можете показать папку с ресурсами?

Comment: @Andrey её нет. Путь указанный на скриншоте к спрайту это всё что у меня есть о возможном местоположении этого спрайта. Вот поэтому у меня и возник вопрос, как этот дефолтный спрайт установить через код.

Comment: если у вас нету папки с ресурсами в проекте то и взять с неё вы не можете

Comment: Попробуйте ради теста. Создайте эту папку в проекте. Поместите изображение и укажите к нему путь. Должно сработать

Comment: @Andrey само собой. Но вопрос был не в этом, а в том как получить доступ к этому спрайту и использовать его через код. Если не через Resources. Load и не через тот путь который я предполагал, то я открыт к предложениям.

Comment: @Andrey Как было указано в моё вопросе. У меня НЕТ этого изображения. Это спрайт используемый Юнити по умолчания для разного рода UI.

Comment: нашел способ
AssetDatabase.GetBuiltinExtraResource<Sprite>("UI/Skin/UISprite.psd")
это должно сработать

Comment: источник 
https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/5fc21bb4ecf4b40ff6630057edaa070252909b2e/UnityEditor.UI/UI/MenuOptions.cs?at=4.6

Comment: @Andrey Да, я тоже видел этот способ, но скрипт не видит AssetDatabase. В любом случае, благодарю за помощь, так как я нашёл ответ, который практически идентичен вашему и решает вопрос с AssetDatabase и вопросом в целом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Ответ на этот вопрос дан на ресурсе GameDevelopment**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/174029/76308)

*Приблизительный перевод:*

Вы можете получить доступ к встроенным дополнительным ресурсам в редакторе. Я полагаю, что если вы сделаете ссылку на спрайт пользовательского интерфейса публичной, это создаст копию для использования в ходе выполнения программы.

В ином случае, путь к спрайту 'UI/Skin/UISprite.psd'

***Пример:***

```
sourceImage = temp.GetComponent<Image>();
sourceImage.sprite = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.GetBuiltinExtraResource<Sprite>("UI/Skin/UISprite.psd");
```

Я бы предложил использовать Sprite.Create (); во время выполнения программы, и вы можете создать текстуру для нее, так что вам не нужно загружать их по умолчанию.